# Modify CSS for Android and iOS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I'm making a responsive landing page but I'm having trouble modifying the HTML elements for Android and iOS. For example:
I change the font-size of an h1 but it doesn't change on iOS but it does on Android.

This is my code:

Style.css:

```css
.first-container {
    
background-image: url("../../../assets/images/desktop/Img\ Head\ desktop.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: start;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0px 18rem;

    h1 {
        font-size: 3.5vw;
        font-weight: 700;
    }


    p {
        padding-top: 2rem;
        padding-bottom: 2rem;
        font-size: 1.25vw;
        text-align: justify;
    }
}

.title-first-container {
    font-size: 1.3rem;

    @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
        font-size: 1.5rem;        
    }
}

.subtitle-first-container {
    font-size: 1.3rem;

    @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
        font-size: 1.5rem;        
    }
}


.first-container-button {
    background-color: #cc2c2c;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 15px 60px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .first-container {
        background-image: url("../../../assets/images/mobile/Img\ Head\ Mobile.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 0rem 4rem;


        button {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }

    .first-container-button {
        background-color: #cc2c2c;
        color: white;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 15px 60px;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .first-container {
        background-image: url("../../../assets/images/mobile/Img\ Head\ Mobile.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 0rem 4rem;

        button {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 8px 20px;
        }
    }

    .first-container-content {
        transform: translate(0px, 30%);
    }
}
```

index.js:

```html
 <div className="first-container">
            <div className="first-container-content">
                <div className="title-first-container">
                    <h1>Cuide do seu <span style={{ color: 'rgba(207, 57, 57,1)' }}>coração.</span></h1>
                    <h1>Eu te ajudo!</h1>
                </div>
                <h2 className="subtitle-first-container">
                    Dr. Maurício Medeiros <br />
                    Cardiologista <br />
                    CRMCE:9091 RQE:11103
                </h2>
                <p className="description-first-container">
                    Médico Cardiologista, formado em 2003 pela <br />
                    Universidade Federal do Ceará. Professor de <br />
                    cardiologia da faculdade UNINTA. <br />
                    Ecocardiografista pela Escola Pernambucana de <br />
                    Ecocardiografia. Título de especialista pela <br />
                    Sociedade Brasileira de Cardiologia (RQE 11103). <br />
                    Proprietário e diretor clínico da CENTROCARDIO <br />
                    SOBRAL, uma clinica especializada em <br />
                    cardiologia na cidade de Sobral- Ceará.
                </p>
                <a href={linkButton} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
                    <button className="first-container-button">Agendar consulta</button>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I mainly want to make the size of the h1 larger than the h2 on the iPhone 12, center the texts and give a minimum distance between the elements.

Comment: Your index.js file has a lot of HTML and very little JavaScript for a file with a js extension...

Comment: Also, [CSS Nesting is relatively new](https://caniuse.com/css-nesting), so the user would have to have a very recent install of iOS to have support...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so first, as one of the comments said, unless you are using React with Sass/Scss I really wouldn't use CSS nesting.

Second, I believe your problem may rest with the `400px` part, there are phone screens wider than that, I always use `500px`, just to be safe